# Bar plot ggplot2 - Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (150): fill, x, y

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hey I know there are lots of questions about this particular error but i still cant find what is wrong, pretty new to R and coding in general. 
here is a link to may data

https://www.dropbox.com/s/qfo5rp7ywgsgxhy/CRERDATA.csv?dl=0

and here is my code to make the graph

## not all used for graph obviously

```
library(car)
library(ggplot2)
library(Rmisc)
library(dunn.test)
library(FSA)
```

## summarizes my data so i can get standard error bars

```
index_sum <- summarySE(CRERDATA, measurevar = "index", groupvars = c("site", "scenario"), na.rm = TRUE)
```

## graph code

```
index_graph <- ggplot(CRERDATA, aes(x = index_sum$site, y = index_sum$index, fill = index_sum$scenario)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = index_sum$scenario), position = position_dodge(), stat="identity") + ylab("Bleaching index") + xlab("Sites") + 
  labs(fill = "scenario") + scale_fill_grey() + theme_minimal() + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = index_sum$index-se, ymax = index_sum$index+se), width = .2, position = position_dodge(.9), color = "red")
```

Comment: Put your code inside the "code" block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have specified `CRERDATA` in the ggplot as `data`, when you are actually using `index_sum`.

Load necessary packages:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(Rmisc)
```

Read data and summarise:

```
CRERDATA <- read.csv('CRERDATA.csv')
index_sum <- summarySE(CRERDATA, measurevar = "index", groupvars = c("site", "scenario"), na.rm = TRUE)
```

Instead of `CRERDATA`, use `index_sum`. You then don't need to use the dollar sign `$` to access columns:

```
ggplot(index_sum, aes(x = site, y = index, fill = scenario)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = scenario), position = position_dodge(), stat="identity") + 
  ylab("Bleaching index") + xlab("Sites") + labs(fill = "scenario") + scale_fill_grey() + 
  theme_minimal() +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = index-se, ymax = index+se), width = .2, position = position_dodge(.9), color = "red")
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: thank you so much, that was so simple but i just couldnt see it